# A Python list of Numpy Arrays to CSV?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a Python list of Numpy arrays storing X, Y, Z coordinates - like this:

```
[array([-0.22424938,  0.16117005, -0.39249256])
array([-0.22424938,  0.16050598, -0.39249256])
array([-0.22424938,  0.1598419 , -0.39249256]) ...,
array([ 0.09214371, -0.26184322, -0.39249256])
array([ 0.09214371, -0.26250729, -0.39249256])
array([ 0.09214371, -0.26317136, -0.39249256])]
```

And I would like to get them into a CSV file so I can plot them in GIS software.  I am new to Numpy arrays and I keep getting errors using methods like numpy.ndarray.tofile().

I can iterate the list using

```
for item in list:
    f.write(str(item))
```

but it writes the data to the text file as binary data.
I just want to have each XYZ value comma separated with each row storing one XYZ value. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module with its [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method:

```
import csv

with open('my_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    csvwriter.writerows(list_of_arrays)
```

Answer (score 3):

`np.savetxt` will write the list:

```
In [553]: data=[array([-0.22424938,  0.16117005, -0.39249256]),
     ...: array([-0.22424938,  0.16050598, -0.39249256]),
     ...: array([-0.22424938,  0.1598419 , -0.39249256]),
     ...: array([ 0.09214371, -0.26184322, -0.39249256]),
     ...: array([ 0.09214371, -0.26250729, -0.39249256]),
     ...: array([ 0.09214371, -0.26317136, -0.39249256]),]
In [554]: np.savetxt('test.txt',data, delimiter=', ', fmt='%12.8f')
In [555]: cat test.txt
 -0.22424938,   0.16117005,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.16050598,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.15984190,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26184322,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26250729,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26317136,  -0.39249256
```

`np.savetxt` really saves an array, but converts the list to array if needed:

```
In [556]: np.array(data)
Out[556]: 
array([[-0.22424938,  0.16117005, -0.39249256],
       [-0.22424938,  0.16050598, -0.39249256],
       [-0.22424938,  0.1598419 , -0.39249256],
       [ 0.09214371, -0.26184322, -0.39249256],
       [ 0.09214371, -0.26250729, -0.39249256],
       [ 0.09214371, -0.26317136, -0.39249256]])
```

It then iterates over rows, and writes

```
f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

where `fmt` is either the full string you provide or one constructed by replicating the shorter `fmt` I provided.

Effectively `savetxt` is doing:

```
In [558]: fmt='%12.8f, %12.8f, %12.8f'
In [559]: for row in data:
     ...:     print(fmt%tuple(row))
     ...:     
 -0.22424938,   0.16117005,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.16050598,  -0.39249256
 -0.22424938,   0.15984190,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26184322,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26250729,  -0.39249256
  0.09214371,  -0.26317136,  -0.39249256
```

Comment: Hey hpaulj, how do you use cat in pyhton?

Comment: @ApolloniaVitelli, it's an `alias` defined for `ipython` on a linux system.  On windows, the defined aliases are different.  Try `%alias` to see what's defined on your system.